# How to publish Polymer 3.x custom element?

Tags: javascript, polymer, frontend, polymer-3.x

I am learning polymer3.x. I made a dummy polymer element. Now i wanted to know how to publish online and use it in some other framework(eg: angular app).

I completed the requirements as mentioned in https://www.webcomponents.org,

- included License file
- tagged versions
- added README file

But while doing "[preview element](https://www.webcomponents.org/preview)" i got `Error - 12: Missing bower.json. Currently, only Bower is supported.` From Polymer version 3, the Polymer team recommends `npm` instead of `Bower`.

How to publish my polymer element, so I can use it in another app (like Angular app)?

Comment: Do you have a `bower.json` file? And what version of Bower are you using ?

Comment: @Pogrindis No. I am installing all the dependencies via `package.json`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2**

[You can now publish your element on NPM and then use the web components page to publish it on the site](https://www.webcomponents.org/publish)

---

**Update 1**

Publishing polymer 3 elements in `webcomponents.org` is not supported yet, it is on the roadmap

[According to Polymer team:](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2018-05-02-roadmap-update)

> The element catalog at webcomponents.org will be updated to support
>   elements built with modules and distributed via npm.

But you can still just publish your element on `npm`

[See How to Publish & Update a Package on npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages)

Answer (score 0):

You can already add elements [published on npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages) to webcomponents.org, it's just the preview function that doesn't work

Once published on npm, you can just enter the name of your package on the [publish page](https://www.webcomponents.org/publish)

One "problem" I have run into, is that you have to have a `repository` field in your `package.json`, otherwise webcomponents.org won't accept it, something like:

```
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "https://github.com/your-name/your-package.git"
},
```