# How to deploy prod bundled Polymer 3 app build?

Tags: polymer-3.x

In my case polymer app or custom element should be deployed to Springs MVC jsp page.

I've expected bundled build will produce a couple of files that should be included in production similar as it is done in case of Angular 2+. But, Polymer put bundled code to `script` tags in `index.html` file.

How should that "output" be deployed to existing non page in production?

Comment: Answered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/52002209/1456164 ?

Comment: Is there then difference between unbandled and bundled preseted builds from the point of view of deploying.